# Camera preview not showing properly in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an Android camera application using the `Camera` hardware class instead of the native camera app. When showing the preview by creating a subclass of the `SurfaceView`, camera is not showing properly: the dimensions and aspect ratio are not well.

I guess this is a common problem with an easy solution, so, does anybody know which should I do?

Comment: can you tell me which device are you using?

Comment: HTC One S (Ville). Does it matter? thank u

Comment: This is tricky to get right. I'd suggest taking a look at [my CWAC-Camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera), either to just use it, or to poke through the code to see what I had to do to get it working (and then only most of the time, so far).